# Htaccess Directive to Show Content of Other Page Pattern URLS

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have the following page patterns:

```
mydomain.com/?myquery=34
mydomain.com/?myquery=38
mydomain.com/?myquery=42
```

Which I would like to access the content via:

```
mydomain.com/myquery/34
mydomain.com/myquery/38
mydomain.com/myquery/42
```

So when a user gets for example mydomain.com/myquery/34 (this page does not exist), he sees the content of mydomain.com/?myquery=34 (this page exists).

I am using the following htaccess rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/myquery/dir1$ /?myquery=dir1 [L]
```

But the rule does not appear to work. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this below rules,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/myquery/(.*)$ index.php?myquery=$1 [L,QSA]
```